# Storing JSX elements inside React State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I hope I'm not the only one who's facing with the problem of processing large amount of data to create JSX elements. The problem with that in my solution, that every time a state or prop changes inside a component, it does the whole processing to create it's children, unnecessarily.

Here's my component:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Input from "./Input";
import { validate } from "./validations";
class Form extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        //inputs: array of objects which contains the properties of the inputs
        //Required.
        inputs: PropTypes.arrayOf(
            PropTypes.shape({
                //id: identifier of the input.
                //Required because the form will return an object where
                //the ids will show which value comes from which input.
                id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,

                //required: if set to false, this field will be accepted empty.
                //Initially true, so the field needs to be filled.
                //Not required.
                required: PropTypes.bool,

                //type: type of the input.
                //Initially text.
                //Not required.
                type: PropTypes.string,

                //tag: htmlTag
                //Initially "input", but can be "select".
                //Not required.
                tag: PropTypes.oneOf(["input", "select", "radio", "custom-select"]),

                //options: options for <select>
                //Not required.
                options: PropTypes.arrayOf(
                    PropTypes.oneOfType([
                        PropTypes.shape({
                            //value: value of the option
                            value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                            //displayValue: if defined it
                            //will be the displayed of the text
                            displayValue: PropTypes.string,
                            //element: for tag: custom-select
                            //must be a JSX element
                            element: PropTypes.object
                        }),
                        //if the value is equal to the display value,
                        //it can be declared as string
                        PropTypes.string
                    ])
                ),

                //minLen: minimum length accepted for the field.
                //If the input doesn't passes, it will not be valid.
                //Initially 0, not required.
                minLen: PropTypes.number,

                //maxLen: maximum length accepted for the field.
                //The characters over the maximum will be cut.
                //Initially 20000, not required.
                maxLen: PropTypes.number,

                //className: class of the container of the input.
                //The structure of the input component is:
                //<div className={className}>
                    //[<label>{label}</label>]
                    //<input>
                    //<p>{errorMessage}</p>
                //</div>
                //Not required.
                className: PropTypes.string,

                //placelholder: placeholder of the input field.
                //Not required.
                placeholder: PropTypes.string,

                //label: label of the input field.
                //Not required.
                label: PropTypes.string,

                //validation: function, which checks
                //if the value entered is valid.
                //Must return a string of an error message if isn't valid.
                //Executes if:
                //-the user clicks outside the field if it has focus
                //-the user clicks on submit button
                //Not required.
                validation: PropTypes.func,

                //process: function, which processes the input entered
                //If the form is ready to submit,
                //the field's value will be processed with it.
                //Not required.
                process: PropTypes.func,

                //initValue: initial value of the field.
                //Not required.
                initValue: PropTypes.string,

                //submitOnEnter: if the user presses the "Enter" key,
                //it submits the form.
                //works only with "input" tags
                //Initially true, not required.
                submitOnEnter: PropTypes.bool
            })
        ).isRequired,

        //onSubmit: function which processes the form.
        //Must receive the form as a parameter, which is the shape of:
        //{[id]: value, [id]: value}
        //Required.
        onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,

        //otherElements: addictional elements to the form.
        //The function must return JSX elements
        //Not required.
        otherElements: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.func),

        //className: className of the form.
        //Not required.
        className: PropTypes.string,

        //buttonTitle: the button's title.
        //Initially "Submit".
        //Not required.
        buttonText: PropTypes.string,

        //focusOn: puts focus on specified element on specified event.
        //Not required.
        focusOn: PropTypes.shape({
            id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            event: PropTypes.bool
        }),

        //collect: collects the specified element id's into one parent.
        //Needs to be an object, where the key is the classname of the container,
        //and the values are an array of the id's of the items needs to collect
        //Not required.
        collect: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.array)
    }

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        const { inputs } = this.props;

        const inputProps = inputs.reduce((obj, {id, initValue: value = ""}) => {
            obj[id] = { value, error: null};
            return obj;
        }, {});

        this.setState({...inputProps}) //eslint-disable-line
    }

    //process with max-length checking
    completeProcess = (val, process, maxLen) => process(val).substr(0, maxLen)

    handleSubmit = () => {
        const inputProps = this.state;
        const errors = {};
        const processedValues = {};

        this.props.inputs.forEach(
            ({
                id,
                required = true,
                validation,
                process = v => v,
                minLen = 0,
                maxLen = 20000
            }) => {
                const { value } = inputProps[id];
                errors[id] = validate(
                    {value, validation, required, minLen}
                );
                processedValues[id] = this.completeProcess(
                    value, process, maxLen
                );
            }
        );

        const errorFree = Object.values(errors).every(e => !e);

        if (errorFree) {
            this.props.onSubmit(processedValues);
        } else {
            const newState = {};

            Object.keys(inputProps).forEach(id => {
                const { value } = inputProps[id];
                const error = errors[id];
                newState[id] = { value, error };
            });

            this.setState(newState);
        }
    }

    renderInputs = () => {
        const { collect } = this.props;
        const collectors = { ...collect };
        const elements = [];


        this.props.inputs.forEach(({
            id,
            validation,
            required = true,
            submitOnEnter = true,
            label,
            initValue = "",
            className = "",
            placeholder = "",
            type = "text",
            tag = "input",
            options = [],
            process = v => v,
            minLen = 0,
            maxLen = 20000
        }) => {
            const value = this.state[id] ? this.state[id].value : initValue;
            const error = this.state[id] ? this.state[id].error : null;

            const onBlur = () => {
                const { followChange } = this.state[id];

                if (!followChange) {
                    this.setState({ [id]: {
                        ...this.state[id],
                        error: validate({value, validation, required, minLen}),
                        followChange: true
                    }});
                }
            };
            const onChange = newValue => {
                const { followChange } = this.state[id];
                const newState = {
                    ...this.state[id],
                    value: this.completeProcess(newValue, process, maxLen)
                };
                if (followChange) {
                    newState.error = validate(
                        {value: newValue, validation, required, minLen}
                    );
                }
                this.setState({ [id]: newState });
            };
            const onEnterKeyPress = ({ key }) => submitOnEnter && key === "Enter" && this.handleSubmit(); //eslint-disable-line

            const focus = () => {
                const { focusOn = {} } = this.props;
                if (id === focusOn.id && focusOn.event) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            const input = (
                <Input
                    className={className}
                    label={label}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    value={value}
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    type={type}
                    tag={tag}
                    options={options}
                    key={id}
                    id={id}
                    error={error}
                    onEnterKeyPress={onEnterKeyPress}
                    focusOn={focus()}
                />
            );
            if (Object.keys(collectors).length) {
                let found = false;
                Object.keys(collect).forEach(parentId => {
                    const children = collect[parentId];
                    children.forEach((childId, i) => {
                        if (childId === id) {
                            collectors[parentId][i] = input;
                            found = true;
                        }
                    });
                });
                if (!found) {
                    elements.push(input);
                }
            } else {
                elements.push(input);
            }
        });
        const collectorElements = Object.keys(collectors).map(parentId => (
            <div className={parentId} key={parentId}>
                {collectors[parentId]}
            </div>
        ));
        return [
            ...elements,
            ...collectorElements
        ];
    }
    render () {
        const {
            className,
            buttonText = "Submit",
            otherElements
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className={`form ${className}`}>
                {this.renderInputs()}
                {otherElements && otherElements.map((e, i) => e(i))}
                <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>{buttonText}</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

Where Input is a Pure Component, but it's not relevant to the question. So as you can see, I tried to make the component as flexible as I can, where I need to define just a few attributes to create almost every type of form. But this flexibility costs much, as it needs to process the properties every time the component renders. As `this.props.inputs` will not change 100%, it wouldn't cause issues if it would be created just when the component mounts. Is it a good solution to move `renderInputs` to `componentDidMount`, and store the elements into `this.state` instead of returning them inside render? If not, what would be the most efficient solution for those problems?

Comment: I don't have an opportunity to analyze the code, but no, it doesn't make sense to store elements. Creating JSX elements is basically `React.createElement` call, which is very simple and very fast. They don't represent actual component instances. They are just plain objects that are intended to be constantly recreated. If you have complex render function such as `renderInputs`, you likely need to extract some components from it. You can make them pure for performance if you believe this will help - or you could memoize `renderInputs` at least, which is more straightforward way to store elements

Comment: You should consider using global state management tools, like React Hooks or Redux. A single, full-utility component is nice, but does not perform well since the more inputs it hold, the more unnecessary re-renders will be triggered from one single input update. Also, form is expected to receive a lot of user interactions, which requires a better solution for performance than local state `Form` component.